# Bootstrap Styling Cart within Navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, cart

I'm trying to style my Cart within the Navbar like below.

[image]

I figured I'd have to make it's own UL with something like "navbar-cart" instead of "navbar-nav" however I was having trouble.

The best success I've had was:

```
.navbar-cart {
padding-top: 7px;
padding-bottom: 7px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
background-color: #4c4c4c;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-cart > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-cart > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-cart > a:active {
font-size: 14px;
text-align: left;
color: #fff;
line-height: 1.3;
padding: 0px;
background-color: transparent;
text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-cart > a:hover {
text-align: left;
color: #fff;
background-color: transparent;
}
```

I was still unable to get cart icon ( with font awesome ) in there nicely... let alone make entire div a dropdown.

Comment: navbar-nav is the default of bootstrap and you'll not get the icon when you change it to something else even though it works and still not display the icon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had to implement the same thing on a website and I kind of like it, need a little bit of tuning on appearance but it works. It uses bootstraps popover. Stuff is written in portuguese but you should understand it. Also the total value of the cart is blade templated.

Navbar code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
 ...some other li's...
          <li>
             <a id="cart-popover" class="btn" data-placement="bottom" title="Carrinho de Compras">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
                 {{ $cart_total == 0 ? "Nada no carrinho!" : ("R$ " . number_format($cart_total, 2, ',', '.'))   }}
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Js to set the content of the popover:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#cart-popover').popover({
    html : true,
    container: 'body',
    content: function() {
        return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
    }
 });
});
```

#popover_content_wrapper is a div with the content of the popover, it has the hidden class so it doesn't show in the page, it's just a normal bootstrap panel.

This is what I get:

[image]
.

jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/5011/

Comment: Looks great. Do you happen to have a live example? I also would like to see what your cart system is like. If able, get me on twitter at "nowlena" if don't want to share publicly.

Comment: @Aaron just did it here: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/5011/  mobile version requires some tweaking, but for large screens which don't collapse it should work OK.

Comment: @Aaron Also, what do you mean my cart system? To internally manage the user's cart I use a github package for Laravel 5:  https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart

Comment: Thank you very much @Polar. I'm currently using something along the lines of https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/5054/ but may switch over to popout like you have above. Also, yes I'm not sure which cart software to go with... i just want something light weight I can drop into my template. May end up using woocommerce but undecided at this time.

Comment: @Aaron Everything depends on which framework you're using if you are using one. Also, if you target mobile users you'd have to fix your cart only showing on hover and making it show on click too. Also, if you think my answer was satisfying, check it as correct please.